# How to compile program with opencv and qt for Yocto linux image?

Tags: linux, qt, opencv, yocto, openembedded

Using Yocto i am able to generate my Linux image and its root file system having libraries for both qt and opencv.

In order to compile QT program there is an SDK **poky-eglibc-i686-meta-toolchain-qt5-cortexa15hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.6.1.sh** .

For compiling Opencv i have another SDK: poky-eglibc-i686-core-image-weston-cortexa15hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.6.1.sh.

QT SDK doesnot have any libraries and header files for opencv which is making difficult to compile a program both with Opencv and QT.

I am successfully able to compile Qt programs and opencv programs using separate SDK.

Is there any SDK which can compile a program with both QT and Opencv?
Or how should i generate one?

Answer (score 3):

My preference is to create an image based SDK, ie an SDK that will match your image. This is done by running:

```
bitbake <your-image> -c populate_sdk
```

If your image includes a Qt5 application and OpenCV, both of those will automatically be installed into your new SDK. You should have the following line in your image recipe:

```
inherit populate_sdk_qt5
```

An alternative is to create your own SDK-recipe, by eg copying [meta-toolchain-qt5](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb) to your own layer and renaming it. Then add:

```
 TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " opencv"
```

That should add `opencv` to your generic Qt5 SDK.

Again, my recommendation is to use the image based approach.

Comment: I'm also using image based approach. My image also contains `inherit populate_sdk_qt5`. This will pull some nativesdk qt tools and it will create `qt.conf` sdk file. I'm not sure if these things are somehow pulled in because of dependencies.

Comment: @TomasNovotny Thank you for your reply. i did the same thing inherit populate_sdk_qt5 and after that bitbake <your-image> -c populate_sdk. It worked.